# how do you write output of sql to a csv file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to oracle table and execute a sql. I need to export result set to a csv file. My code is below:

```
import pyodbc
import csv

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=11g;UID=test101;PWD=passwd")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchall()
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for line in row:
        a.writerows(line)

cursor.close()
```

when I do print to line within for loop, I get something like this:

```
('Production', 'farm1', 'dc1prb01', 'web')
('Production', 'farv2', 'dc2pr2db01', 'app.3')
('Production', 'farm5', 'dc2pr2db02', 'db.3')
```

this is not working. Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Can you explain - *this is not working* ? How is it not working? What else are you getting?

Comment: He just used the wrong method for csv.writer, Padraic answer is the correct one.

Comment: I get this error:  with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be writerow for a single row:

```
 a.writerow(line)
```

`writerows` expects an iterable of iterables, so it will iterate over the substrings writing each char individually.

If you want to use writerows call it on row:

```
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            a.writerows(row)
```

If you are using python2 remove `newline=''`, newline is a *python*3 keyword:

```
  row = cursor.fetchall()
    with open('data.csv', 'w') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            a.writerows(row)
```

Comment: still not able to execute the sql

Comment: If you see `('Production', 'farm1', 'dc1prb01', 'web')` how is the sql not working? Using writerows on that will give you `P,r,o,d,u,c,t,i,o,n. ....`

Comment: If I dont use the csv, and just print the line, I can print.

Comment: @user1471980, newline="" is for python3 not python2